# What is xmlValue doing in this code snippit?

Tags: r

One way I have been learning has been to work my way slowly through other people's code, figure out what they did. I found [this neat bit of code](https://gist.github.com/drewconway/791559) on GitHub that returns the number of search results for a search term.

I understand every line of this function, EXCEPT the line that begins with "search.value". What is this line doing? I know it takes an html div with a number and extracts the number, but for the life of me I have no idea HOW it does that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)

google.counts<-function(s){
search.url<-paste("http://www.google.com/search?q=",gsub(" ","+",s),sep="")
search.html<-getURL(search.url)
parse.search<-htmlTreeParse(search.html,useInternalNodes = TRUE)
search.nodes<-getNodeSet(parse.search,"//div[@id='resultStats']")
search.value<-strsplit(xmlValue(search.nodes[[1]])," ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]
return(as.numeric(gsub(",","",search.value,fixed=TRUE)))
}
```

Comment: You can set a variable `s` and run the code line by line to see what is returned every time. E.g. `s = "r language"` and see what `search.nodes[[1]]` is and how it becomes after `xmlValue`ing it. You might want to see `methods(xmlValue)` and view codes of the methods with `XML:::xmlValue._` (e.g. `XML:::xmlValue.XMLNode`). `XML:::trim` might, also, be useful since it is in many method functions of `xmlValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `debug` functionality

```
debug(google.counts)
google.counts("test")
```

This will put you into a debugging "browser" and you can keep on hitting enter to step through each line of function step by step.  You can also see contents of the variables as you would do in a normal R prompt.